# MVC Template editors and post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates, editortemplates

I'm at a beginner with ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have a problem. Basically I have this controller:

```
public ViewResult Login()
{
    return View(new LoginViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (authProvider.Authenticate(model.LoginUserName, model.LoginPassword))
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
        }
        TempData["message"] = "Nome utente e/o password errati!!!";
        return View();
    }
    return View();
}
```

That implements a simple login view. I created also a ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Il nome utente è obbligatorio")]
    [UIHint("TextBoxLogin")]
    public string LoginUserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LoginPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I created the EditorTemplate:

```
@model string

<input name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix" id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix"data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="@ViewData["HelpMessage"]" value="@Model" />
```

So far so good. The problem is in the view. If I put this in the view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) { 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
    @Html.EditorForModel() 
    <p><input type="submit" value="Log in" /></p> 
}
```

It works like a charm (but it puts a lot of not wanted html into the page), in fact, when I click on the submit button it goes to the POST actionResult of the controller. If I put this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Account",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p class="username">
        <label for="UserName">Nome utente</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LoginUserName, new { HelpMessage = "Il nome utente è obbligatorio!!!" });
    </p>
    <p class="password">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LoginPassword)
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </p>
}
```

It does not go on the post actionresult but always on the Get one. I want to put this type of code (the last one) in wich I can setup exactly the html but I want that it goes on the POST Actionresult, can someone help me to understand why?

-----------------update----------------
Here is the HTML generated:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<link href="/static/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/static/css/jquery_ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link href="/static/css/lt_ie9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<script src="/static/js/jquery_1_10_2.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery_ui.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery_ui_function.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<div id="top">
    <div class="wrapped">
        <div id="logo">TITLE</div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="content" class="user_student">
        <div class="wrapped">
            <div class="login_intro">
                <h2>TEST</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="login_input">
                <p id="error_messages"></p>
                <h2>THIS ONE MAKES GET REQUEST</h2>
<form action="/Account/Login" method="post">                        <p class="username"><label for="UserName">Nome utente</label>
                            <!--<input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text"/>-->
                            <input name="LoginUserName" id="LoginUserName"data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Il nome utente &#232; obbligatorio!!!" />;
                        </p>
                        <p class="password"><label for="LoginPassword">Password</label>
                            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Il campo LoginPassword è obbligatorio." id="LoginPassword" name="LoginPassword" type="text" value="" />
                        </p>
                        <p><input type="submit" value="Log in" /></p>
</form>                <p class="hidden">old</p>
            </div>
            <div class="login_footer">
                <p>FOOTER</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <h2>THIS ONE MAKE POST REQUEST</h2>
<form action="/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f" method="post"><div class="editor-label"><label for="LoginUserName">LoginUserName</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input name="LoginUserName" id="LoginUserName"data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LoginUserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
<div class="editor-label"><label for="LoginPassword">LoginPassword</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Il campo LoginPassword è obbligatorio." id="LoginPassword" name="LoginPassword" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LoginPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Log in" /></p> 
</form><script src="/static/form-validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery_form_validator_function.js"></script>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "unwanted html"? I don't see any problem with your second view. does it still not work if you put `[HttpGet]` attribute on your GET Login action?

Comment: 1) Use network tab of Chrome dev tools to verify that it is type POST.  2) Did you put `[HttpGet]` on `Login()` ?  MVC will use the first action it finds that satisfies the criteria.  If you don't have it tagged with `[HttpGet]` then that means it works for both GET and POST and therefore will use the first action.

Comment: I'm also curious if you have `[Authorize]` attribute on your `AccountController`, if so, are you missing the `[AllowAnonymous]` attributes on the action methods?

Comment: Guys, thanks for the answer but it still does not work :-( Here some answer:
@DavidG : the unwanted HTML is the html generated from 
@using(Html.BeginForm()) { 
    @Html.EditorForModel() 
    <p><input type="submit" value="Log in" /></p> 
} 
it puts a lot of div and customize css classes.
I don't make [Authorize] on the AccountController, the AccountController check the login option.

Comment: @AaronLS I put [HttpGet] but it still does not function. I look at the developer Google tools and it send a get not a post request!!! But i set-up 
using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Account",FormMethod.Post))...why?

Comment: If it is sending a GET rather than a POST then there is something else wrong here. What HTML is being generated? Can you update your question with that?

Comment: I updated it, thanks for the answer

Comment: There's no way that HTML can make a GET instead of a POST unless something in your browser is interfering.

Comment: I use chrome...strange behaviour. I will try with firefox and see what happen...the strange thing is that with editorformodel it makes post request and not get...if us the browser also che editformodel should not go...shouldn't it?!?

Comment: Perhaps a proxy server is in the way? Try saving the `<form>...</form>` in an HTML file and loading it in a browser directly. Also try Chrome in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out what is the problem...and of course it is the most stupid thing in the world.
In the rended code there is a open  just after the body and, inside it, the form that MVC put from razor view.
Thanks for everyone for the help paricularly to @DavidG